# Roughly how much Co2 is generated per kWh of electricity generated

Tags: environmental-protection, coal

I’m interested to know how much Co2 is generated by a coal fired power station to produce 1kWh of electricity for electrical grid

Comment: Welcome at EarthScience.SE. Which resources did you use in trying to answer the question on your own? Looking for _"co2 emissions coal fire plant per kwh"_ in your favorite search engine should yield a huge heap of useful results. It looks a bit like a homework question. Moreover, I am not sure whether this question is in the scope of EarthScience.SE. I am voting to close this question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's on-topic here or not, but it would certainly be on topic at sustainability.stackexchange.com. I suggest asking there!

Comment: @ben if you want, you could flag it for mode attention, and ask for migration to [sustainability.se]

Answer (score 1):

About 900 grammes of CO2 for each 1kWh of electricity.

There is some variation: very modern super-critical coal plants can be lower. But 900g is a reasonable central estimate.

Note that that's just CO2 from combustion. It can be higher, when we include CO2 and CH4 emissions from the rest of the coal supply chain too.